# Having difficulty getting multi-line Powershell regex to work - no matches

Tags: powershell, parsing

I referred to several examples I was able to search, which seemed highly pertinent, but am still unable to get this to work.

My input looks like this, from a dhcp server stats command, and I've confirmed that $output is getting defined properly with lines that look like:

```
MIBCounts:
        Discovers = 63911.
        Offers = 3903.
        Delayed Offers = 0.
        Requests = 29199.
        Acks = 273080.
        Naks = 71.
        Declines = 0.
        Releases = 395.
        ServerStartTime = Tuesday, March 27, 2012 7:38:53 PM
        Scopes = 34.
        Scopes with Delay configured= 0.
        Subnet = 10.31.0.0.
                No. of Addresses in use = 203.
                No. of free Addresses = 40774.
                No. of pending offers = 0.
        Subnet = 10.32.3.0.
                No. of Addresses in use = 0.
                No. of free Addresses = 0.
                No. of pending offers = 0.
        Subnet = 10.32.100.0.
                No. of Addresses in use = 48.
                No. of free Addresses = 145.
                No. of pending offers = 0.
        Subnet = 10.32.101.0.
                No. of Addresses in use = 34.
                No. of free Addresses = 159.
                No. of pending offers = 0.
```

So what I tried was this, but got no matches:

```
$output=$(netsh -r myserver dhcp server show mibinfo)

$dhcp_regex=@"
(?s)Subnet = (\d\.\d\.\d\.\d)\.\W+
.*No\. of Addresses in use = (\d+)\.\W+
.*No\. of free Addresses = (\d+)\.\W+
"@

$dhcp_record= {
    @{
        subnet=$matches[0]
        inuse=$matches[1]
        free=$matches[2]
    }}


$output -match $dhcp_regex

$matches
```

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for your first line instead:

```
(?s)Subnet = (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\W*
```

You'll also want to look at each line separately:

```
$output | % { $_ -match $dhcp_regex }
```

# Append `| Out-Null` if you don't want each line printed on your screen.

$matches[1]

Edit: here is a more complete example.

```
$dhcp_regex = 'Subnet = (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'
$dhcp_regex2 = 'in use = (\d+)'
$output | ? { $_ -match $dhcp_regex -or $_ -match $dhcp_regex2} | % { $Matches[1] }
```

Edit: here is a multiline example.

```
$dhcp_regex = '(?m)Subnet = (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\r\n.*in use = (\d+)'
$output | Out-String | % { $_ -match $dhcp_regex }
$matches
```

hat tip: http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/80160-powershell-regex-help.html

Edit: Looks like `(?m)` is not actually necessary. `Out-String` is the secret sauce.

Comment: Ok, tried the first, nothing.  Tried the second, and yes, it works, but it doesn't really represent the "inline, need to match the whole pattern" objective.  If it happened to get 2 lines of "in use" in a row, I'd still get output.  In this particular case, our input format we're parsing is extremely well known, and we can rely on the pattern of alternation being followed.  For me however, I treat these situations as instructive and want rigorous solutions that will stand up when I know my data input is not as clean. I'd like to make the original form work as it's more exact.

Comment: Fair enough. That's how I approach these things too. I will amend my comment with another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Changed the regex you provided to add the extra data element.

```
$dhcp_regex='(?m)Subnet = (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\.\r\n.*in use = (\d+)\.\r\n.* free Addresses = (\d+)\.'
```

That works fine now - much appreciated!  I may spend some time when I'm bored (hehe) to discover in what nuanced way what we were doing before was failing.

Comment: Was this to be a comment on @northben's answer? If so, please move.. If this was intended to be the correct answer, don't forget to mark it as "accepted".